# tw cannot be resolved in twitter4j

Tags: java, twitter4j, twitter-streaming-api

I'm using twitter4j to recognize a user. However, piece of code written to recognize the user throws an error.

```
twitterStream.addListener(listener);
    User user = tw.showUser("lalindasampath"); //tw is your Twitter variable from twitter4j.Twitter tw=tf.getInstance();
    long id = user.getId();
    twitterStream.addListener(listener);
    FilterQuery filtre = new FilterQuery();
    filtre.follow(id);
    twitterStream.filter(filtre);
```

My error is : tw cannot be resolved.

Does anyone know what should I import to fix this error?

Comment: Where have you defined `tw`?

Comment: As in comment it should be defined in twitter4j.Twitter. I'm importing the twitter4j.package .

Comment: No, that is not how it works (and also not what that comment tries to say).

Comment: Thanks @MarkRotteveel , I found the solution for that. But now I have a new question.                                                                                                    build() has already being called. TwitterStream twitterStream = new TwitterStreamFactory(cb.build()) .getInstance(); TwitterFactory tf=new TwitterFactory(cb.build()); twitter4j.Twitter tw=tf.getInstance();                                   How to fix this?

Comment: If you have a new question: post a new question; don't use comments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to create the `Twitter tw` variable as you did [on your other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36638763/listen-tweets-in-real-time). Something like this:

```
    ConfigurationBuilder cb = new ConfigurationBuilder();
       cb.setDebugEnabled(true)
            .setOAuthConsumerKey("")
            .setOAuthConsumerSecret("")
            .setOAuthAccessToken("")
            .setOAuthAccessTokenSecret("");
 TwitterFactory tf=new TwitterFactory(cb.build());  
 twitter4j.Twitter tw=tf.getInstance();
```

Comment: But build() has already being called.                                                                TwitterStream twitterStream = new TwitterStreamFactory(cb.build())
                  .getInstance();
          TwitterFactory tf=new TwitterFactory(cb.build());  
          twitter4j.Twitter tw=tf.getInstance();